# opengl sphere clipping

Tags: opengl, glut, clipping

I've been experimenting with programs from my text book that involved clipping 2-D polygons using glOrtho and then creating glutWireSpheres in gluPerspective. My goal is to clip half the sphere with a plane, however, I am having trouble clipping 3-D objects. I created a toggle button to show the sphere clipped and unclipped, however, the button instead shows the sphere moving in a ellipse motion I believe.

Here is my drawscene for creating the sphere

```
   double eqn0[4] = {1, 0, 0.0, -60}; // Data for clipping plane 0.

   // Choose window.
   glutSetWindow(id2);
   gluLookAt(0.0, 3.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE0, eqn0); // Specify clipping plane 0.


   if (isClip0) glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0); // Clip points s.t. z > 0.25.
   else glDisable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0);

   glPushMatrix();
   glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glutWireSphere(1.0, 10, 10);
   glPopMatrix();

   glFlush();
```

And here is my toggle

```
case '0':
         if (isClip0 == 0) isClip0 = 1;
         else isClip0 = 0;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;
```

Can someone help me get in the right direction for clipping 3-D objects? Because this will work on 2-D polygons, yet when I try to apply it to spheres, the toggle button doesn't even act like a toggle.

---

EDIT: Full code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#  include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#  include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#define PI 3.14159265

using namespace std;

// Globals.
static int id1, id2; // Window identifiers.
static int isClip0 = 0; // Is clipping plane 0 enabled?
static int isClip1 = 0; // Is clipping plane 1 enabled?
static int isClip3 = 0; // Is clipping plane 0 enabled?
static int isClip4 = 0; // Is clipping plane 1 enabled?

// Drawing routine for first window.
void drawScene1(void)
{
   // Choose window.
   glutSetWindow(id1);

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   // A red square.
   glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);    
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      glVertex3f(10.0, 10.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(40.0, 10.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(40.0, 40.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(10.0, 40.0, 0.0);
   glEnd();

   glFlush();
}

// Drawing routine for second window.
void drawScene2(void)
{

   double eqn0[4] = {1, 0, 0.0, -1000}; // Data for clipping plane 0.

   // Choose window.
   glutSetWindow(id2);

   gluLookAt(0.0, 3.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE0, eqn0); // Specify clipping plane 0.

   if (isClip0) glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0); // Clip points s.t. z > 0.25.
   else glDisable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0);

   glPushMatrix();
   glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glutWireSphere(1.0, 10, 10);
   glPopMatrix();

   glFlush();
}

// Initialization routine for first window.
void setup1(void) 
{
   // Black background.
   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

// Initialization routine for second window.
void setup2(void) 
{
   // Green background.
   glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}

// Reshape routine for first window.
void resize1(int w, int h)
{
   glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();

   // Non-square aspect ratio squashes the square.
   glOrtho(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, -1.0, 1.0);

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
}

// Reshape routine for second window.
void resize2(int w, int h)
{
   glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
   glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluPerspective(60.0, (float)w/(float)h, 1.0, 50.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();


}

// Keyboard input processing routine shared by both windows.
void keyInput(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch(key) 
   {
      case 27:
         exit(0);
         break;
        case '0':
         if (isClip0 == 0) isClip0 = 1;
         else isClip0 = 0;
         glutPostRedisplay();
         break;
      default:
         break;
   }
}

// Main routine.
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

   // First top-level window definition.
   glutInitWindowSize(250, 500); 
   glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);

   // Create the first window and return id.
   id1 = glutCreateWindow("windows.cpp - window 1"); 

   // Initialization, display, and other routines of the first window. 
   setup1();
   glutDisplayFunc(drawScene1); 
   glutReshapeFunc(resize1);
   glutKeyboardFunc(keyInput); // Routine is shared by both windows.

   // Second top-level window definition.
   glutInitWindowSize(250, 500); 
   glutInitWindowPosition(400, 100);

   // Create the second window and return id.
   id2 = glutCreateWindow("windows.cpp - window 2"); 

   // Initialization, display, and other routines of the second window. 
   setup2(); 
   glutDisplayFunc(drawScene2); 
   glutReshapeFunc(resize2);
   glutKeyboardFunc(keyInput); // Routine is shared by both windows.

   glutMainLoop();

   return 0;   
}
```

Sphere is dealt with in drawScene2

Comment: I don't see any reason why it should move when you press your button (as long as you did not forget some "break" statement in your switch case) You really should call glLoadIdentity() before doing the gluLookAt, otherwise it would move every time you draw the scene. Also, you should be aware that with a clip plane at distance -60, clipping a sphere with a radius of 10 will not have any effect.

Comment: Yeah the break statement is there after post redisplay. Also, I have always seen load identity in the resize function and not a draw function. Conversely, when I insert the LoadIdentity before gluLookAt, nothing happens now when I press the toggle button. As for the -60 value, that was just an experiment. Even when I change the value, I have the same effect of a sphere moving in an elliptical path. There are slight changes with the sphere disappearing depending how small that value gets, but it still doesn't make sense why the sphere is moving instead of being clipped.

Comment: Well, with the code snippes you gave, it is totally unclear why it moves. Maybe some other problem with the matrices or matrix mode. Can you post more code? The whole code for all the glut callbacks might be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I will post all the code in my main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after adding a glLoadIdentity() right before the gluLookAt(), the movements will go away (as I already had suggested...). And when one sets a useful clip plane equation, the clipping works as expected, too. As you define a sphere with radius 1 around the object space center, setting

```
 GLdouble eqn0[4] = {1, 0, 0.0, 0.5};
```

will result in the sphere being clipped at x=-0.5, so 3/4 of it is still visible, as one would expect.

Comment: Oh this is good. I forgot to switch up the values for eqn0 after inserting loadIdentity. Thanks